# PHP Array - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

What am i missing here ? I have some PHP code which calls a fuction which in turn runs a query against a google Firebase DB and returns an array with Team Names

The test Array looks like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Ducks
[1] => Select
)
```

The code i use is

```
 <select>
    <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
    <?php
    include_once 'game_functions.php';
    $Teams = GET_TEAMS();
    foreach($Teams as $item){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo strtolower($item); ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Which complains with following error

**Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in **/var/www/html/Fire/NewPlayer.php** on line 31

Comment: Clearly `GET_TEAMS()` isn't returning an array as you expect

Comment: Always provide a complete example: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm sure that the problème is in the level of the variable $Teams; In GET_TEAMS() function; i tested it with the array in the first line and that worked perfectly.

Try:

```
var_dump($Teams);die();
```

Show as what that gives.

Comment: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  NULL
}

Comment: try;
        var_dump(GET_TEAMS());die();

then share the results with us

Comment: my first comment was the output of the var_dump

Comment: I figured out the issue, do to so many files being used the function created an array but did not pass it on only printed the array. So after back tracing i found that the function printed but didn't return the actual array.

Comment: I know, i just want to be sure that the return response of the GET_TEAMS() function so we be sure that the problem is in the response of this function so you can fixe it :)

Comment: That's why i asked for the var_dump(GET_TEAMS()); beacause i saw your reponse about it and you write Array ( [0] => Lady Ducks [1] => Selects @ BKHS ) wich is not an array because var_dump function givs you the type of each element and also it gives you the number of elements just like the var_dump($Teams) that gived you array(1) which means one element.